# How to draw row from DB with the same ID as the previous row, but from different table?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have this method below, it pulls random questions from sqlite database, from tbale named tblPitanja (db has 3 tables in it) and four possible answers. After user answers the questions I now need to pull the question and answers with the same ID from the same sqlite database but from different table. I need to ask some addition question related to the previous question. How to do that? The hardest part for me now is how to know what ID was in previous question.

```
private void nextQuestion() {
        counter++;
        TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.createDatabase();

        try{ 

            mDbHelper.open(); 

            Cursor c = mDbHelper.getTestData(generateWhereClause());

            mAnsweredQuestions.add(c.getLong(0));

            List<Answer> labels = new ArrayList<Answer>();

            labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(2), true));
            labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(3), false));
            labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(4), false));
            labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(5), false));

            tacanOdg = c.getString(2);


            Collections.shuffle(labels);

            byte[] image_bytes = c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("PITANJE"));
            ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(image_bytes); 
            Bitmap bp=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

            if(counter < 11){
            flag.setImageBitmap(bp);

            bOdgovor1.setText(labels.get(0).option);
            bOdgovor1.setTag(labels.get(0));
            bOdgovor1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            bOdgovor2.setText(labels.get(1).option);
            bOdgovor2.setTag(labels.get(1));
            bOdgovor2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            bOdgovor3.setText(labels.get(2).option);
            bOdgovor3.setTag(labels.get(2));
            bOdgovor3.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            bOdgovor4.setText(labels.get(3).option);
            bOdgovor4.setTag(labels.get(3));
            bOdgovor4.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            rezultat.setText(counter + "/10");
            score.setText("Score: " + brojacTacnihOdgovora);

            }else{
                brojacVremena.cancel();

            }
        }
        finally{ 
            mDbHelper.close();
        }
```

EDIT:

Database helper:

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
private static String TAG = "DataBaseHelper"; // Tag just for the LogCat window
//destination path (location) of our database on device
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/rs.androidaplikacije.flags/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME ="pitanja.sqlite";// Database name
private static SQLiteDatabase mDataBase; 
private final Context mContext;

public DataBaseHelper(Context mojContext) 
{
    super(mojContext, DB_NAME, null, 1);// 1? its Database Version
    DB_PATH = mojContext.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
    this.mContext = mojContext;
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException
{
    //If database not exists copy it from the assets


        this.getReadableDatabase();
        this.close();
        try 
        {
            //Copy the database from assests
            copyDataBase();
            Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase database created");
        } 
        catch (IOException mIOException) 
        {
            throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
        }
    }
    /*Check that the database exists here: /data/data/your package/databases/Da Name
    private boolean checkDataBase()
    {
        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        //Log.v("dbFile", dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists());
        return dbFile.exists();
    }
    */

    //Copy the database from assets
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException
    {
        InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int mLength;
        while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0)
        {
            mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
        }
        mOutput.flush();
        mOutput.close();
        mInput.close();
    }

    //Open the database, so we can query it
    public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException
    {
        String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        //Log.v("mPath", mPath);
        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
        //mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
        return mDataBase != null;
    }
    @Override
    public void close() 
    {
        if(mDataBase != null)
            mDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
        }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        Log.w("DataBaseHelper", "Upgrading database!!!!!");
          onCreate(arg0);

    }


}
```

Adapter:

```
public class TestAdapter 
{
    protected static final String TAG = "DataAdapter";

    private final Context mContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private DataBaseHelper mDbHelper;

    public TestAdapter(Context context) 
    {
        this.mContext = context;
        mDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(mContext);
    }

    public TestAdapter createDatabase() throws SQLException 
    {
        try 
        {
            mDbHelper.createDataBase();
        } 
        catch (IOException mIOException) 
        {
            Log.e(TAG, mIOException.toString() + "  UnableToCreateDatabase");
            throw new Error("UnableToCreateDatabase");
        }
        return this;
    }

    public TestAdapter open() throws SQLException 
    {
        try 
        {
            mDbHelper.openDataBase();
            mDbHelper.close();
            mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        } 
        catch (SQLException mSQLException) 
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "open >>"+ mSQLException.toString());
            throw mSQLException;
        }
        return this;
    }

    public void close() 
    {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

     public Cursor getTestData(String whereClause)
     {;
         try
         {
             String sql ="SELECT * FROM tblPitanja WHERE 1 = 1 " + whereClause + " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1";

             Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
             if (mCur!=null)
             {
                mCur.moveToNext();
             }
             return mCur;
         }
         catch (SQLException mSQLException) 
         {
             Log.e(TAG, "getTestData >>"+ mSQLException.toString());
             throw mSQLException;
         }
     }
     public Cursor getTestDataGradovi()
     {;
         try
         {
             String sql ="SELECT * FROM tblGradovi LIMIT 1";

             Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
             if (mCur!=null)
             {
                mCur.moveToNext();
             }
             return mCur;
         }
         catch (SQLException mSQLException) 
         {
             Log.e(TAG, "getTestData >>"+ mSQLException.toString());
             throw mSQLException;
         }
     }
     public Cursor getTestDataValute()
     {;
         try
         {
             String sql ="SELECT * FROM tblValute LIMIT 1";

             Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
             if (mCur!=null)
             {
                mCur.moveToNext();
             }
             return mCur;
         }
         catch (SQLException mSQLException) 
         {
             Log.e(TAG, "getTestData >>"+ mSQLException.toString());
             throw mSQLException;
         }
     }
}
```

And my new method for additional question (it's not finished yet, it's just copied my first method with some changes to use .getTestDataGradovi() from db adapter class:

```
private void nextQuestionGrad() {
         flag.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         dodatnoPitanje.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);
            mDbHelper.createDatabase();

            try{ 

                mDbHelper.open(); 

                Cursor c = mDbHelper.getTestDataGradovi();

                mAnsweredQuestions.add(c.getLong(0));

                List<Answer> labels = new ArrayList<Answer>();

                labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(2), true));
                labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(3), false));
                labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(4), false));
                labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(5), false));

                tacanOdg = c.getString(2);

                Collections.shuffle(labels);


                dodatnoPitanje.setText(c.getString(1));

                bOdgovor1.setText(labels.get(0).option);
                bOdgovor1.setTag(labels.get(0));
                bOdgovor1.setOnClickListener(clickListenerGrad);

                bOdgovor2.setText(labels.get(1).option);
                bOdgovor2.setTag(labels.get(1));
                bOdgovor2.setOnClickListener(clickListenerGrad);

                bOdgovor3.setText(labels.get(2).option);
                bOdgovor3.setTag(labels.get(2));
                bOdgovor3.setOnClickListener(clickListenerGrad);

                bOdgovor4.setText(labels.get(3).option);
                bOdgovor4.setTag(labels.get(3));
                bOdgovor4.setOnClickListener(clickListenerGrad);

                score.setText("Score: " + brojacTacnihOdgovora);


                }
            }
            finally{
                mDbHelper.close();
            }
     }
```

Comment: Doesn't your table have an ID that is returned in the cursor?

Comment: Do you mean in database helper class?

Comment: As long as you keep that class a secret, how do you anybody else to answer that question? (But it looks like you've added the ID to `mAnsweredQuestions`.

Comment: OK, I will edit my first post and add db helper and adapter, maybe you can help me then. tnx

Comment: Here you go mate, added all i've got. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the table structure of `tblPitanja` and `tblGradovi`? What are the IDs that should match?

Comment: I have _ID, PITANJE, ODGOVOR, OPCIJA1, OPCIJA2, OPCIJA3 columns. I have 200 entries in all tables. I need if in first random question method was drawn for example question with _ID 36, I don't want next question from another table to be random, I want the question with _ID 36 also to be called in my nextQuestionGrad() method. All tables have the same structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `getTestDataGradovi` to load one specific record, identified by its ID:

```
public Cursor getTestDataGradovi(long id) {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM tblGradovi WHERE _ID = " + id;
    Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
    c.moveToNext();
    return c;
}
```

Inside `nextQuestion`, you need to save the ID of the current question somewhere:

```
mCurrentID = c.GetLong(0);
```

Inside `nextQuestionGrad`, you can the use that saved ID to get the corresponding other question:

```
Cursor c = mDbHelper.getTestDataGradovi(mCurrentID);
```

Comment: Thank you good sir, worked like a charm! I will study it in details today. Learned something new.

Comment: Can you answer me only this (learning purposes). Why do we use getLong and long variable mCurrentID when my ID is of type int?

Comment: You are using `long` yourself when adding the ID to `mAnsweredQuestions`.

Comment: Yes I do, but that's some line I found on stack overflow, even then I didn't get why to use long instead of int.